# Rotate a display by custom angle

Tags: xorg, xrandr

`xrandr` can rotate the screen by 90, 180, 270 and 360 degrees.
But what if I have to rotate the screen by 45 degrees or by 237 degrees?

`xrandr`'s `transform` seems to be promising but unable to catch the thing I am looking at.

I would like to know this to understand below picture:
[image]

Comment: I would imagine that the original image was rotated and cut up into pieces with Photoshop and then displayed with the displays rotated "normally", i.e. not rotated at all; probably something like 1 Raspberry Pi per screen? Sometimes you don't need complicated setups to reach a result as in the image. Note how 2 displays are square...

Answer (score 1):

[The `xrandr` manpage](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.xhtml) gives the transformation matrix; for an angle T:

```
cos T  -sin T  0
sin T   cos T  0
  0       0    1
```

So to rotate a display by 45°, anti-clockwise:

```
xrandr --output DP-2-2 --transform 0.7071,-0.7071,0,0.7071,0.7071,0,0,0,1
```

(replacing `DP-2-2` as appropriate).

To restore the display:

```
xrandr --output DP-2-2 --transform 1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
```

OR

```
xrandr --output DP-2-2 --transform none
```

Rotating the display in this way causes the logical display to be extended so that the monitor’s viewport has something to display.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in Question. It does help to rotate at desired angle but also creates void blank space on logical screen. Is there any way to fill that up ?

Comment: Oh, OK, so your question isn’t the general one in the title, but specifically how to re-create the display in the photo, is that right?

Comment: Yes. Indeed. And I am desperate to do so.

Comment: You can probably create a logical display that expand on multiple, rotated screens.
Maybe it would be easier to rotate the picture.
PS: I ran the command and I can barely see my screen. Please help I'm stuck.